# Is GO Supported in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm sorry for the question but I am terribly a newbie in using MySQL Database. I just want to know if GO in MS SQL is supported in MySQL. Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GO` is not a SQL keyword, not even a Transact-SQL keyword.

It is a batch separator for Microsoft SQL Server **tools**.

See [GO (Tansact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) on MSDN:

> Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities.

And:

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the **sqlcmd** and **osql** utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

It is not supported by any other databases.

Answer (score 3):

no. the Semicolon `;` is the equivalent for mySql

unless you are trying to do something like

```
insert into...
GO 10
```

to execute 10 times.

then its not possible